# SwiftUI Preview won't show

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I've had this issue happened to me twice now. I'm working in a project and the previews for my SwiftUI views won't show. The entire preview pane is just not there. The only way I've been able to fix it is recreating the project again.

This happened to me in both Xcode 13 (Intel based Mac) and 14 (M1 Mac). Is this a known issue or is there a setting I'm missing to enable and disable previews in a SwiftUI project?

Comment: Ctrl-alt-Enter and be sure to have a preview defined in the source file you are watching

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Thank you @PtitXav! That works! Is there a menu command for this too?

Comment: I think it is called canvas in one of the submenu on top right of editor window.

Answer (score 4):

On a Mac computer, using the "Option-Command-Enter" key combination worked well. However, the "Canvas" button did not work and caused a preview crash. (iOS 16, xcode 14, M1 air)